# Chrome Extension: Integrating with Google Calendar API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I'm developing a Chrome extension, which needs to call the Google Calendar API. I start with the quick start tutorial (for javascript) here:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

And it works. But when I copied and pasted all the code into the extension html (which is popup.html in the official tutorial), it doesn't work. I cannot see the "Authorize" button in the popup page.

I suspect that the inputted "Authorized JavaScript origins" caused error (now I inputted "http://localhost:8000"). Or am I following a wrong example for making a Chrome Extension? Thanks!

Comment: Rightclick the popup, click Inspect, and you'll see the errors in the devtools console. You'll see you need to extract the inline code to a separate js file, and to add the API site in [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm! You're my teacher. I was replying late because I want to read through the materials before asking the next question.

After I followed your suggestion to extract inline code to a separate js file, all things work except this one:

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>

Do you mean I should keep this and add "https://apis.google.com/js/*/" in permissions in the manifest?: